# How to validate html forms in python Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a HTML form inside a landing page and I want to send the forms data by ajax to /data rout.
The problem is validating this HTML form in backend.
I know about Flask WTF form but using this method will generate form on backend which is not my case.

```
from flask import Flask, request, url_for
...
@app.route("/data", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def get_data():
if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.form["username"]
    ...
```

My html form:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

One hard way is to validate every field using regex and write several if conditions for them. I'm wondering for easier way?

Comment: How do you want to validate the form exactly? What checks do you want to do?

Comment: Not empty. Email, Phone, Checked and much more ...

Comment: But I don't want to user regex for all inputs. It must be a better way?

Comment: If you don't want to use the validation methods provided by Flask-WTF you will need to write them yourself, indeed. Is there a specific reason you don't want to use Flask-WTF?

Comment: You are right common way was using Flask-WTF which I did for my other forms but I have several landing pages which are designed by UI designers and plain HTML/CSS so I prefer to keep them and do the validation on my side.

Comment: I would just import the WTForms validators you need and run them on your input yourself without creating a form. At least it saves you from creating your own regex for email, phone, date, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `Webargs`

```
from webargs import flaskparser, fields

FORM_ARGS = {
    'email': fields.Email(required=True),
    'username': fields.Str(required=True),

@app.route("/data", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def get_data():
    if request.method == "POST":
        parsed_args = flaskparser.parser.parse(FORM_ARGS, request)
```

But as long as you know the format of the incoming data you can still use WTFs for capturing the posted info (you dont need to render WTForms on a page for it to work), for example:

```
# import blurb    

class Form(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[InputRequired()])
    email = EmailField('Email', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(4, 128), Email()])

@app.route("/data", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def get_data():
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Form()  # will register fields called 'username' and 'email'.
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            # do something
```